# How to use solana-client from a tokio async runtime?

Tags: solana-client, runtime

I am working in a tokio async environment, built from `tokio::runtime::Runtime::block_on`.

```
fn start() {
    ...
    enter preformatted text here
    let runtime =
            tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();
    runtime.block_on(async {
        async_start();
    });

}

async fn async_start() {
...
}
```

I have some good reasons to have a non-async start function (dynamic libraries reason), and I need this async_start() to be async as I'm doing other async operations.
However, when I'm trying to call a simple function on solana client, I get an error:

code:

```
let rpc_client = RpcClient::new(provider);
let block_hash = rpc_client.get_latest_blockhash().unwrap();
```

error:

```
thread 'tests::test_signer' panicked at /home/erudyx/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/solana-rpc-client-1.18.7/src/rpc_client.rs:4050:9:
can call blocking only when running on the multi-threaded runtime
```

From tokio's doc, it look like `Runtime::new` should build a multi-threaded environment: "This results in the multi threaded scheduler, I/O driver, and time driver being initialized"

So I don't understand why I am facing this.